# Android Studio - How can I send a Bitmap photo to API by sending its bytes in a String?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

The title says it all, I need to send a photo taken from my phone to an external API that is expecting a String containing the photo. This string should be the bytes of the photo. How can I implement that?

I've tried using retrofit to connect to the API, but I can't convert the bytes array to a single string.

This is the code I have right now:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private void analiseIt(Bitmap photo, Context context)  {

    Uri photoPath = saveToInternalStorage(photo,context);

    FileUploadService service = ServiceGenerator.createService(FileUploadService.class);

    Call<JsonObject> call = service.upload(toBinary(myBytes));
    call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {

            Log.d("Response from server: ", new Gson().toJson(response.body()));

            Float reading =  Float.valueOf(new Gson().toJson(response.body().get(READING)));
            Float accuracy = Float.valueOf(new Gson().toJson(response.body().get(ACCURACY)));

            mLastMeasurement = new Measurement(reading, accuracy, new TimeMeasurement(TimeMeasurement.OVERNIGHT_FASTING));
            insert(mLastMeasurement);
            Log.v("Upload", "success");

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Upload error: ", t.getMessage());
        }


    });
}

String toBinary( byte[] bytes )
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bytes.length * Byte.SIZE);
    for( int i = 0; i < Byte.SIZE * bytes.length; i++ )
        sb.append((bytes[i / Byte.SIZE] << i % Byte.SIZE & 0x80) == 0 ? '0' : '1');
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Can you send it as a [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) string? Or will the API not be able o handle it?

Comment: @nobody I don't really know, the API has to receive the photo's bytes. How could I convert the array to a base64 string?

Comment: Or you send a string or the bytes of the jpg or png file. Not the bytes of a bitmap.

Comment: @blackapps yes but the API is only expecting a string

Comment: You should ask them and then tell us how exactly you have to send a file.

Comment: @blackapps they only told me that they need to receive the photo's bytes

Comment: Then who invented that string?